# Coordinate of a pixel of an image to coordinate on the texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

A `Texture2D` is mapped on a sphere. Thanks to `GetPixel(raycastHit.texturecoord)` I can get the pixel value of this texture, when, for instance, a ray hit the sphere. So if I convert an image `I` to a texture `T` and map `T` on a `GameObject` `G`, I can get the pixel value from `G` to `I` (`G--textureCoord-->T--GetPixel-->I`). If I convert those (x,y) coordinates into world coordinates, I can trigger event on certain colors, so it works. I use [this solution](http://answers.unity.com/answers/372156/view.html) to perform pixel to world position.

But I can't do the opposite. Imagine that I have a list of bounding boxes for different objects on the image `I` (so with coordinates between `I.width` and `I.height`). If I convert those coordinates (bx1, bx2) into world coordinates it simply doesn't work.

I noticed that when I compare the `GetPixel` value when I target a given color on `G` with my controller, I don't get the same pixel coordinates as the one on the original image.

In the end I want to get the texture coordinate from an image (`G<--textureCoord_to_word_coordinates--T<--?????---I`).